# gulp watch: no gulpfile found

Tags: gulp, aurelia

I am trying to run the Aurelia skeleton-es2016-asp.net5 demo.
I am following the steps in read me.
I opened a command box and ran

```
npm install gulp
```

which seemed to work
however ehrn I now run

```
gulp watch
```

I get an error

```
No gulpfile found
```

Comment: Did you checked that you are in the right directory? You need to be in the directory where your gulpfile is laying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you created `gulpfile.js` containing the gulp tasks ?

If No, you need to `add gulpfile.js` to your directory root and may write some default task in it for testing,

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
gulp.task('default', function () { console.log('Hello Gulp!') });
```

If yes, Try Installing gulp globally `npm install -g gulp`

Comment: I was confused about the directory.  Found the gulpfile.js and changed to that directory.